# Blending/merging N images with more weight for brighter areas in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Need to merge/blend two images  in ImageMagick such that brighter parts of each image will get more weight towards the final blended result. For example, if there are two images with a light spot in position A and B respectively, the darker parts of the second image in the position A will be given, say 10%, weight while the brighter part from the second image would get 90% of the weight during final merging. I have tried the following in ImageMagick without success:

1. convert -luminize
2. convert -evaluate-sequence mean
3. composite -dissolve P

Comment: try either `evaluate-sequence add` or put the intensity of each image into its alpha channel and then use `-flatten`

Comment: @fmw42: can you please elaborate on 'put the intensity of each image into its alpha channel and then use -flatten'? Some code example will be great.

Comment: `@sm535` post two example images so I can see what you are working with. Basically the alpha channels act as masks for blending. So the brighter it is the more weight it will get. But you can modify the masks to increase the weights by increasing the brightness in the masks.